# Спряжение глагола "карбовать"

Tags: грамотная-речь, спряжение

[Вот](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_culinary/974/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) что такое *карбование:*

Если говорить вкратце, это надрезание мяса неглубокими косыми надрезами (простите за тавтологию) для более быстрого прожаривания и для втирания в них специй. В углублениях они остаются лучше, чем в плоских кусках.

У [Даля](http://slovardalja.net/word.php?wordid=12855) есть ***глагол*** с несколько иным смыслом:

> КАРБОВАТЬ что, южн. и зап. помечать нарезкою, зарубать, делать зарубку, затесь. Карбованый че бак, кур. вяленая, провесная рыба, с надрезами по бокам.

(Прим.: наверно, имеется в виду "чебак" слитно.)

То есть у Даля рыба, сейчас основное мясо, но это близко.

Ещё в современных [кулинарных словарях](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_culinary/975/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C) встречается *карбование овощей, фруктов и теста.*

---

*Итак, меня интересует, можно ли спрягать **карбовать*** или ***накарбовать*** в настоящем и будущем времени?  В прошедшем, полагаю, спрягать можно.

Comment: Любопытно, а карбованец от этого слова возник  - как "южный" вариант рубля? :)

Comment: @Alex_ander: да, я тоже заметил! ;)

Comment: Тут ещё слово **скарб** оказалось родственным - через немцев с поляками: https://lexicography.online/etymology/krylov/%D1%81/%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B1

Comment: Ха, интересно!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если это глагол, то он обязан спрягаться. Иногда не все формы есть, но сама категория спрягаемости обязана существовать ))) Во всех временах.

То есть спрягается наверняка, вопрос - как.

Если считать -ова суффиксом, то ответ очевиден. ***Я (на)карбую, ты (на)карбуешь...** 
А вот если это часть корня, возможны варианты. Или как ***ковать*** (то есть по той же схеме, что с суффиксом), или же примерно как ***плавать*** (я карбоваю, ты карбоваешь).
Первое вероятнее.

Comment: Спасибо! А можно тогда сказать в будущем "я накарбую"?

Comment: Естественно. Приставка на парадигму спряжения вообще не влияет. Я даже ответ почистил ради отражения этого момента.))

Answer (score 1):

**Карбова́ть, карбу́ю, -у́ют**, *перех*. (Малор. карбова́ти, польск. каrbowac, с немецк. karben). Делать нарезы... Помечать нарезками, зарубать, делать зарубки (напр. на бирке). Чертить... Наносить раны... — Ср. покарбова́ть, накарбова́ть.

**Карбова́ться, -бу́юсь**. Страдат. залог глаг. карбова́ть. О рыбе: быть разрезаемой.

[Словарь русского языка, составленный Вторым отделением Императорской Академии Наук](https://books.google.ee/books?id=tEQgBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA556&lpg=PA556&dq=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%8E&source=bl&ots=XmWARCkwfl&sig=ACfU3U1Uqhm0NmqatJe3f-gWCaJ7KvbXLw&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjFltKg8Y_mAhXGtYsKHRoBDL84ChDoATAHegQICxAB#v=onepage&q=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%8E&f=false)

Comment: Спасибо, Римма!

Answer (score 0):

Конечно, можно. Все эти словари - всё это чушь.

Вот ты, как творец, имеешь право, например, на авторское словообразование.

Вот берёшь ты любые буквы, к примеру абвгд. Это - производящая основа. Прибавляешь к ней суффикс -ова, образуешь глагол абвгдовать. Дериват производный. Ура!

Ну, а далее, ясное дело, глагол "абвгдовать" встраиваем, так сказать, в русскую морфологическую систему.

То есть глядим на сходные глаголы на -ова — и что там видим? А то, что: а) при спряжении в суффиксе -ова происходит грамматическое (морфологическое, морфонологическое) чередование -ова/уй (бык-ова-ть — я бык-уй-у); б) глаголы на -ова, вообще говоря, хех, спрягаются — имея окончания первого спряжения.

Вот и выходит: абвгд-ова-ть — я абвгдую, мы абвгдуем, ты абвгдуешь и т. д.

Твой глагол даже и в словарях отмечен, тогда уж грех не спрягать его - по морфологической модели, ясен перец.

Карбовать. Карбую, карбуем, карбуешь и т. д. Карбуй, Вася!

Твой вопрос вообще несущественен, как по мне.

Comment: Хорошо, но у "победить" же нету 1-го лица будущего времени.

Comment: У победить "нет" 1 лица не потому, что это бог установил в качестве железного закона, а потому, что так "сложилось". Победю - звучит паршиво, оттого, наверное, и не утвердилось в языке. Но вот попробуй привести хоть один глагол на -ова без формы 1-го лица единственного числа.

Comment: С ходу не приходит в голову. *Победю - звучит паршиво* — зато "побеjу" очень красиво звучит. ;)